# Overflow in python

Tags: python

オーバーフローのエラーです。
GDの中でxを更新しているときにderivで発生していると思われますが解決策がわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

> OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

```
# y = x^4 - x^3
def function(x):
    return x**4 - 2 * (x**3) + 1

# minimum: y = -11/16, x = 3/2
def deriv(x):
    return 4 * (x**3) - 6 * (x**2)


def GD(deriv, init, eta, iter=100):
    '''
    :param deriv: derivative of the function you want to optimize
    :param init: start point, initial value
    :param eta: leaning rate, step size
    :return: history
    '''
    eps = 1e-5
    x = init
    x_history = [init]
    for i in range(iter):
        x_ = x - eta * deriv(x)
        if abs(x - x_) < eps:   # convergence condition
            break
        x = x_
        x_history.append(x)
    return np.array(x_history)


etas = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]
'''
We check the behavior of Gradient Descent compared with the different eta
'''

for i, eta in enumerate(etas):
    tracks = GD(deriv, 2.0, eta)

    plt.subplot(2, 2, (i+1))

    plt.title("eta: " + str(eta) + ", iter: " + str(len(tracks)))

    x = np.arange(-0.3, 1.0, 0.01)
    y = function(x)
    plt.plot(x, y, linestyle="-", c="black")
    plt.plot(tracks, function(tracks), 'x', c="r")

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: eps の値(1e-5)はこれで良いのでしょうか？ また、deriv 関数の計算式も適切なのかどうか不明です。例えば、`4 * (x**-3) - 6 * (x**-2)` とすれば収束しますが…

Answer (score 1):

まず、OverflowErrorは非常に大きい値を取り扱おうとした場合に送出されます。

> 算術演算の結果が表現できない大きな値になった場合に送出されます。
>   https://docs.python.jp/3/library/exceptions.html#OverflowError

解決策ですが、何をしたいのかが質問文からだと不明なので、コードから分かる回答を書きます。

不要なnp（numpyですかね？）を取り除き、 `deriv` 関数のreturn前に `print(x)` を挿入した結果が以下のようになりました。

```
2.0
1.2
1.3728000000000002
1.4686874222592001
1.4957044497076786
1.4995483345721634
1.4999545886920822
1.4999954563946214
2.0
0.3999999999999999
0.5407999999999998
0.7652256661503998
1.109435299670023
1.4940155127489982
1.5047018074535845
1.4961854140988777
1.5030167905684966
1.497564703119691
1.5019340154484542
1.4984438048562072
1.5012391469460173
1.4990049957566633
1.5007936281024734
1.499363585488775
1.5005081597589578
1.49959285234464
1.5003253203321703
1.4997394897067555
1.5002082453712682
1.4998332996170376
1.5001332936164338
1.4998933224637065
1.5000853147177737
1.4999317307566415
1.5000546042092862
1.4999563094765538
1.500034947837555
1.4999720387986786
1.5000223670846855
1.4999821051315547
1.500014315126218
1.4999885474072088
1.5000091617594458
1.4999926703909918
1.5000058635582716
1.4999953090708673
2.0
-1.2000000000000002
5.020800000000003
-136.9853594222595
4157744.941243001
-1.1499881294113451e+20
2.4333246462810442e+60
-2.30526123625319e+181
```

この辺りから、GDのforループ内で扱っているxの値がループの途中から非常に大きくなっていることが原因と分かります。

Comment: 解決策としてはどうすれば正常に動作しますか？

Comment: コードの意図（何をしようとしているのか）が分からないので、「正常に動作」が何を指すかも分かりません（オーバーフローが出るような実装があり、その通りに動いています、以上のことが分かりません）。このコードで実現しようとしていることを *質問文に追記* して頂けると、回答が提供出来るかもしれません。